# Error: Server error Google app engine with express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, server-error

Im using GAE for my nodejs express backend. It worked earlier, but suddenly I keep getting

Error: Server error. 
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

**My error logs is like this :**

default[20181129t203637]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500

default[20181129t203637]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500

default[20181129t203637]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500

default[20181129t203637]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500

I tried adding favicon.ico to my public folder and install npm serve-favicon for the favicon.ico but same error still persist. I thought it was a limit but I tried changing accounts, changing different express project, the same error still comes out.

**my app.yaml file :**

runtime :nodejs8

instance_class: F4_1G

Also have cron.yaml file but I haven't run the cron job yet.

There is nothing wrong with my project when it s run locally. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have active instances ready to handle requests, which causes them to time out while App Engine loads your code into a fresh instance. You can mitigate this by [reducing the time it takes to load your code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#loading_requests) or by [implementing warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests#enabling_warmup_requests) to keep your instances alive when there isn't any traffic.